# Repetition in comparative constructions

Tags: comparison, repetition

> Dubbing animations and movies is much harder than **dubbing** documentaries.

Is it necessary to repeat *dubbing* here?

Comment: "more harder" is ungrammatical. The repetition of **dubbing** is OK. I would recommend it, for clarity, but native speakers often would not repeat it.  You could always recast:  Documentaries are much harder to dub than animations and movies.

Comment: @tromano thank, "much more" was copied by mistake from the original text of a learner.

Comment: I had it backwards in my suggested recast, but you get the idea. That recast should say "Documentaries are much *easier* to dub than animations or movies" or "Animations and movies are much harder to dub than documentaries".

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care for the repetition, try

> Animations and movies are much harder than documentaries to dub.

or

> Animations and movies are much harder to dub than documentaries.

or (if you're very fussy)

> Animations and movies are much harder to dub than documentaries are.

Answer (score 2):

As TRomano pointed out, "more harder" is ungrammatical (though frequently seen, sometimes as humor).

Repeating "dubbing" is important, in the form of the sentence you give, because it's not completely clear without re-reading that it's *dubbing* documentaries that's hard.  TRomano's rephrasing would be a good way to avoid repeating "dubbing" if that's what you want to do.

Comment: thanks, "much more" was copied by mistake from the original text of a learner